# Variable names with parameters

Tags: c

So I have some code here that I have been studying. It converts decimal numbers to binary. The code runs smoothly but what's bugging me are the variables. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long int decimalNumber, remainder, quotient;
    int binaryNumber[100], i=1, j;

    printf("Enter any decimal number: ");
    scanf("%ld",&decimalNumber);

    quotient = decimalNumber;
    while (quotient!=0) {
        binaryNumber[i++]= quotient % 2;
        quotient = quotient / 2;
    }
    printf("Equivalent binary value of decimal number %d:       ", decimalNumber);

    for (j = i -1 ; j> 0;  j--)
        printf("%d",binaryNumber[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

I really find the variables confusing. Can someone tell me what is actually happening with the variables? Especially the one with `binaryNumber[100]`,`binaryNumber[i++]`, `binaryNumber[j]`, and the expression `binaryNumber[i++] = quotient % 2`

Comment: The code doesn't "run smoothly" as it won't compile, se http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Sir it is only a snippet of the overall code. I bet it won't run as there is no #include <stdio.h> in my post

Comment: Sir, you need to read a C tutorial that explains how variables, arrays, pointers and operators work. Your problem is much bigger than you think and too big for Stack Overflow. We are not exactly a beginners tutorial site, but we do like beginners here, so bear with us until you start writing your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`binaryNumber` is an array of `ints`, i.e. of integers. It is of size 100. It goes from 0...99 (`binaryNumber[0]` is the first element and `binaryNumber[99]` is the last). The array can contain 100 integers, of different or equal values. They don't actually have to be of value 0...99 but anything else that is in the range of `int` (read comment).
When you perform `int binaryNumber[100]` you define this array.
When you perform `binaryNumber[i++]` you access the element in the location `i` of this array, and then increment `i`. Meaning you perform `i = i + 1;`.
Same goes for `binaryNumber[j]`.
When you perform `binaryNumber[i++] = quotient % 2` you *assign* the value of `quotient % 2` to the `binaryNumber` array at position `i` like stated before (and increment `i`).

If you're wondering about the modulus operator (`%`) read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: I really find your answer so hard to understand sir. Please forgive me as I am new to Programming.

So when you say 'binaryNumber[100]' does it mean it's limited to a value of 100 only? or 100 being pre-assigned to the variable 'binaryNumber'?

Comment: I edited my answer for more clarity

Comment: The `ints` are not limited to value 100, but to much higher values (2^15 - 1). but the *index* is limited to 0 till 99

Answer (score 0):

**`binaryNumber[100]`**: This is actually an `array of 100 integers`. The first `integer` in the `array` could be accessed by `binaryNumber[0]` etc.

**`binaryNumber[j]`**: This means the `(j-1)th` integer in the array.

**`binaryNumber[i++]`**: Lets say `i=3` when this statement runs. `binaryNumber[i++]` is equivalent to `binaryNumber[3]`, which is the 4th integer. However, after this statement is executed, `i` is incremented to `4`.

**`quotient % 2`**:
 `%` is actually the modulus operator. Example: `13 % 4 = remainder of 13/4 = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

binaryNumber[100] : it is an array , a sepuence of elements of type "long int" you can access a spesific element using "array[index] = value" .

binaryNumber[i++] : access the element nember i then increament i , example if i=1 then you acces binaryNumber[1] then i become 2 (after usage ).

binaryNumber[j] : access the element nember j , j is a variable and can be used as a index ,  then you will acces the element nember the current value of j .

binaryNumber[i++] = quotient % 2 : it tell the compiler to let the element nember i in the binaryNumber take the value of quotient % 2 that is the math modulos , like 9%2=1 ; 5%3=2 , the rest of the quotient pear 2

comment for more informations .

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do the conversion is a loop and shift. You can put it in a function to make the conversion look nice. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>   /* for CHAR_BIT */

void binprn (const unsigned long v);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    long unsigned a = argc > 1 ? strtoul (argv[1], NULL, 10) : 4327;

    printf ("\n %lu decimal,  binary: ", a);
    binprn (a);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}

/** unpadded binary representation of 'v'. */
void binprn (const unsigned long v)
{
    if (!v)  { putchar ('0'); return; };

    size_t sz = sizeof v * CHAR_BIT;
    unsigned long rem = 0;

    while (sz--)
        if ((rem = v >> sz))
            putchar ((rem & 1) ? '1' : '0');
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/dec2bin

 4327 decimal,  binary: 1000011100111

$ ./bin/dec2bin 10

 10 decimal,  binary: 1010

$ ./bin/dec2bin 127

 127 decimal,  binary: 1111111
```

Comment: Nice solution. However it's not an answer to the question.

Comment: Yeah... the OP doesn't understand what an array is, but let's put some `size_t`, `const unsigned long`, bit shifting, ternary operators, `strtoul` etc...